# NHibernate.Search with Lucene.NET without using DB?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, lucene.net

Could I use NHibernate.Search only with lucene’s index without database? Because I would like to store all data only in my lucene’s index, but I really like features in NHibernate.Search.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, as they are tightly coupled. The point of the NHSearch/Lucene.NET/NHibernate integration is that you can do a full text search, but the results returned are domain entities, i.e. from the database.

So, without storing them in the database, there would be no way for NHSearch to inflate the domain objects it finds in the Lucence index.

One other approach would be to look at one of the document databases such as Raven.